# how to make angularjs variable smaller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have div with "ng-repeat "  if i want to show just a part of value .
for example instead of full {{file.Name}} i want just 20 first part of string 
what should i do ?

```
 <pre> 

<div ng-repeat="file in Attachment">

<div style="position:relative;padding:1px; float:left">

<div onmouseover="AttachmenHover({{file.Name}})" >

    <a  href="{{file.Url}}" >

    <img  src="../../../_layouts/RykaUI/Images/files/{{file.Sufix}}.png" />

    <br />

    {{file.Name}}</a>

 </div>

 </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay I would use a filter :
like this:

```
<div onmouseover="AttachmenHover({{file.name | cutIt}}"
```

JS:

```
    yourapp.filter('cutIt', function () {
            return function (key) {
              if(key.length < 20) {
                    return key
                 }
               else return key.substring(0, 20);
            };
        });
```